# Socketio Not Posting Within NGINX Flask Application

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a Flask application running behind NGINX and I am using Gunicorn to deploy. When I deploy, everything works perfectly fine, I can hit my servers IP and see the app running with no issues, however when I execute an action that uses socketio, the action does not get passed to the backend and I believe this is an issue with my configuration on NGINX. My conf.d file has the following

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_IP;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

I deploy the app with

`gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 app:app`

Within my app.py I am running the socketio server with

`socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=80, debug=True)`

Also seeing this within console...

```
socket.io.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MuA1z9K net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Everything works locally. Please keep in mind, I am fairly new to Flask deployments with socketio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection to socket.io was set incorrectly. I should have had var socket = io(); in my js script as opposed to var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:8000'); per [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on port 8000, so your proxy_pass statement should go to that port, not 5000:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
```

Also note that when you run your server via gunicorn, the `socketio.run()` line does not execute, that is used when you don't use a third party web server such as gunicorn or uwsgi, and I'm guessing is what you use locally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That change didn't work unfortunately though. Do I need a directory /socket.io because I don't have one. It's simply built into the app.py and template files

Comment: Socket connection in js is:

        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');

and I'm getting failed header responses in the XHR.

Comment: The `/socket.io` URL is handled internally by the Socket.IO server, you do not need to have that directory in your system. What is your connection statement in the client/